# Не могу сделать отсчет времени от конкретной даты

Tags: javascript, время, счетчики

```js
/*
 function repit(timeRace) {
 setInterval(timeLeft(),500);
}
предполагаемая функция обновления счётчика
*/
```

День добрый.
Пытаюсь реализовать функцию, которая отсчитывает время до предстоящего события.
Саму функцию реализовал, но при этом хочу, чтобы счётчик шёл постоянно,а не при каждом обновлении страницы. Знаю, что это можно сделать как-то через `setInterval()`, но не получается.
Функция `timeLeft(timeRace)`, где timeRace-время события, до которого идёт отсчет, вычитается, соответственно,настоящее время.

```js
function timeLeft(timeRace) {
  let dateToday = new Date();
  if (dateToday > timeRace) {
    return "Гонка уже прошла"
  } else {
    let daysLag = Math.floor((timeRace.getTime() - dateToday.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    let hoursLag = Math.floor((timeRace.getTime() - dateToday.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600) - daysLag * 24);
    let minitesLag = Math.floor((timeRace.getTime() - dateToday.getTime()) / (1000 * 60) - daysLag * 24 * 60 - hoursLag * 60);
    let secondsLag = Math.floor((timeRace.getTime() - dateToday.getTime()) / (1000) - daysLag * 24 * 60 * 60 - hoursLag * 60 * 60 - minitesLag * 60);
    hoursLag = checkTime(hoursLag);
    minitesLag = checkTime(minitesLag);
    secondsLag = checkTime(secondsLag);
    return daysLag + ":" + hoursLag + ":" + minitesLag + ":" + secondsLag;
  }
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  }
  return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function timeLeft(timeRace) {
  let dateToday = new Date();
  if (dateToday > timeRace) {
    return "Гонка уже прошла"
  } else {
    let daysLag = Math.floor((timeRace.getTime() - dateToday.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    let hoursLag = Math.floor((timeRace.getTime() - dateToday.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600) - daysLag * 24);
    let minitesLag = Math.floor((timeRace.getTime() - dateToday.getTime()) / (1000 * 60) - daysLag * 24 * 60 - hoursLag * 60);
    let secondsLag = Math.floor((timeRace.getTime() - dateToday.getTime()) / (1000) - daysLag * 24 * 60 * 60 - hoursLag * 60 * 60 - minitesLag * 60);
    hoursLag = checkTime(hoursLag);
    minitesLag = checkTime(minitesLag);
    secondsLag = checkTime(secondsLag);
    return daysLag + ":" + hoursLag + ":" + minitesLag + ":" + secondsLag;
  }
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  }
  return i;
}

var timeRace = new Date(2019, 5, 1);
setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById("message").textContent = timeLeft(timeRace);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="message"></span>
```